# application runs from command line, but cannot start as init.d script - openWrt

Tags: init.d, openwrt

Got a problem with my service written in C. It runs as an init.d service and has been working fine for many months on many devices. Today I've made some changes in the software and very strange thing occurs. I upgraded the package and noticed that it does not start by init.d, but when I try to run it invoking the command manually it runs perfectly well. That application gives a lot of diagnostic information to the console, but I am not able to see its output when trying to run it as a service. Is there any way to log the output of an application run as an init.d service?

Kal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are logging/debugging facilities in OpenWrt.

Set `PROCD_DEBUG=1` to see debugging information when starting or stopping a procd init script. Also, `INIT_TRACE=1 /etc/init.d/mything $action` Where `$action` is start/stop etc.

More information could be found in [OpenWrt wiki](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/procd-init-scripts?s%5B%5D=procd&s%5B%5D=debug#debugging).